# yii2 home page is shown in all the routes when the baseurl is set to domain name

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When I set the base url as example.com/ it shows only the home page in all urls. Like it masks the url with homepage in all links of the site. But when its set to '/' it works well. But with using '/' as base url breaks some link. So I want to use base url as my domain name.

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => 'http://example.com/',
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    ],
-----
----
]
```

Comment: is this happening on live domain ?

Answer (score 1):

According to docs `baseUrl` is:

> The relative URL for the application.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$baseUrl-detail

"relative" means that it should not contain a host name. You probably need to set [`hostInfo`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$hostInfo-detail):

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'hostInfo' => 'http://example.com',
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    ],
    // ...
]
```